# Passing the outputs from a module when the module is created using a for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

This links to my the previous question, click the link for the rest of my code and how it all fits together: [Use output value from module that has a for_each set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704743/use-output-value-from-module-that-has-a-for-each-set/65712403#65712403)

Whilst the answer was helpful in solving the issue and allowing me to run the pipeline, I think there is an error because of the way the VM is generated using the for_each on the module. This results in the incorrect value being passed to the network_security_rule. Below is an example of the error:

```
Error: Error Creating/Updating Network Security Rule "nsr-sbox-http80" (NSG "module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg" / Resource Group "rg-sbox-app"): network.SecurityRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: Code="ResourceNotFound" Message="The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg' under resource group 'rg-sbox-app' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"

  on main.tf line 58, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "fico-app-sr-80":
  58: resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "fico-app-sr-80" {
```

outputs.tf

```
output "linux_vm_ips" {
  value = azurerm_network_interface.dwp_network_interface.private_ip_address
}

output "linux_vm_nsg" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.dwp_network_security_group.name
}
```

At first I thought it was because the NSG isn't being created, but I checked the console and it does create it. The issue is the NSG is created in the module for each VM. The VM's are created by looping over the variable in tfvars file. How do I pass the NSG name created in the module to the security rule which is outside of the module?:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "fico-app-sr-80" {
  name                        = "nsr-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-${var.vm_identifier}${var.instance_number}-http80"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "*"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "80"
  source_address_prefixes     = ["module.fico_web_vm.linux_vm_ips"]
  destination_address_prefix  = "VirtualNetwork"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg_fico_app.name
  network_security_group_name = "module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg"
}
```

```
# Network Security Group
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "network_security_group" {
  name                = "nsg-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-${var.vm_identifier}-${var.vm_name}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.location
}
```

Something to note as well, is that the var.vm_name iterates through the key of each map and this makes up part of the name of the NSG.

module in main.tf:

```
module "fico_app_vm" {
  for_each                     = var.app_servers
  source                       = "../modules/compute/linux_vm"
  source_image_id              = var.app_image_id
  location                     = var.location
  vm_name                      = each.key
  vm_identifier                = "${var.vm_identifier}${var.instance_number}"
  vm                           = each.value
  disks                        = each.value["disks"]
  resource_group               = azurerm_resource_group.rg_fico_app.name
  directorate                  = var.directorate
  business_unit                = var.business_unit
  environment                  = var.environment
  network_rg_identifier        = var.network_rg_identifier
  subnet_name                  = "sub-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-be01"
  diag_storage_account_name    = var.diag_storage_account_name
  ansible_storage_account_name = var.ansible_storage_account_name
  ansible_storage_account_key  = var.ansible_storage_account_key
  log_analytics_workspace_name = var.log_analytics_workspace_name
  backup_policy_name           = var.backup_policy_name
  enable_management_locks      = true
}
```

tfvars:

```
app_servers ={
  app-1 = {
    size           = "Standard_E2s_v3"
    admin_username = "xxx"
    public_key     = "xxx"
    disks          = [32, 32]
    zone_vm        = "1"
    zone_disk      = ["1"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised what my error was. I needed to change this:

```
network_security_group_name = "module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg"
```

to this

```
network_security_group_name = module.fico_app_vm[each.key].linux_vm_nsg
```

But I also needed to reference the value in the source address prefixes. So to reference the key I created another variable and changed this:

```
source_address_prefixes     = ["module.fico_web_vm.linux_vm_ips"]
```

to this:

```
source_address_prefix       = module.fico_web_vm[each.value.web_server].linux_vm_ip
```

I also had to change to source_address_prefix and thats why the type error was occurring!

The security rule now looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "fico-app-sr-80" {
  for_each                    = var.app_servers
  name                        = "nsr-${var.environment}-${var.directorate}-${var.business_unit}-${var.vm_identifier}${var.instance_number}-http80"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "*"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "80"
  source_address_prefix       = module.fico_web_vm[each.value.web_server].linux_vm_ip
  destination_address_prefix  = "VirtualNetwork"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg_dwp_fico_app.name
  network_security_group_name = module.fico_app_vm[each.key].linux_vm_nsg
```

And variable looks like this:

```
app_servers = {
  app-1 = {
    size           = "Standard_E2s_v3"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    public_key     = xxxx
    disks          = [32, 32]
    zone_vm        = "1"
    zone_disk      = ["1"]
    web_server     = "web-1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the problem that you read the previous answer not carefully. The answer shows you need to change the security group name like this:

```
network_security_group_name = module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg
```

There are no double-quotes. Double-quotes means it's a string. But you need to use the module attribute, not a string with a value `"module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg"`. The error also shows it directly.

Comment: I did remove the double quotes initially, but when I do that I get the following error:
`Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on main.tf line 69, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "fico-app-sr-80":
  69:   network_security_group_name = module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg

Inappropriate value for attribute "network_security_group_name": string
required.`

Comment: @Lucky7865 Can you share the complete code? I don't know if you use the module attribute in the root main.tf file to create the NSG rule.

Comment: @ Charles Xu Yes, so the NSG rules are created in the main.tf alongside the calling module and the network security group is in the linux_vm module. https://gist.github.com/Ali19904/99901a77bb49553af63eb5f2f6f983f3

Comment: @Lucky7865 It seems nothing wrong in the code. Can you output the `module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg` to check if it's right?

Comment: When I run the outputs command, I get `No outputs found' but I have the outputs defined in the outputs file. As I have a for_each set on the modules, do I need to access the outputs by each.key maybe?

Comment: @Lucky7865 I mean you add output in the same file of the module with the value `module.fico_app_vm.linux_vm_nsg`.

Comment: I added it to the same file where the module is referenced as you mentioned and i got the following error: 
`Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 520, in output "linux_vm_nsg":
 520:   value = module.fico_web_vm.linux_vm_nsg
    |----------------
    | module.fico_web_vm is object with 1 attribute "web-1"

This object does not have an attribute named "linux_vm_nsg".`

Comment: @Lucky7865 You can make all the NSG rule resources as comments for the test.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out what the error is, it's related to not referencing the key in the module. Will post the answer

Comment: @Lucky7865 I didn't see you use the for_each in the `azurerm_network_security_rule`, so I don't think can use your answer without the for_each directly.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I've updated answer to show how it all links together.